# How can I efficiently replace specific temperature values in a pandas dataframe with the average of related locations?

Tags: pandas, loops

How to replace daily temperature (column name) value of some rows (location) by the average values of some of other rows (locations)?

I have a daily temperature dataset by location (lat, long) for 20 years. So the columns are date, location, temperature. Now for each day I would like to replace the temperature values of certain rows with an average temperature of some related locations. Like the following relationship, left hand side locations are that I want to replace with the average values of locations on right hand side:

| Target loc | average Loc |
| --- | --- |
| 150.85, -34.55 | "150.85, -34.50", "150.80, -34.55", "(150.85, -34.60", "150.9, -34.55" |
| 151.10, -33.95 | "151.05,-33.95", "151.10,-34.00", "151.15, -33.95" |
| 151.10, -33.85 | "151.05, -33.85", "151.10,-33.80", "151.15,-33.85" |

I tried the following code but somehow python taking so long to execute. FYI, there are around 11millions rows in the main data.

```
`# Load the dataset from a CSV file
    allData = pd.read_csv('temperature_data.csv')

`# Define the locations for which you want to calculate the daily mean
    toReplace = ['150.85, -34.55', '151.10, -33.95', '151.10, -33.85']`

`# Define the other locations to average
    toAverage = [["150.85, -34.50", "150.80, -34.55", "(150.85, -34.60", "150.9, -34.55"],  ["151.05,-33.95", "151.10,-34.00", "151.15, -33.95"], ["151.05, -33.85", "151.10,-33.80", "151.15,-33.85"]]`

`# Iterate over each row in the dataset
    for index, row in allData.iterrows():
    # Check if the row's location is in the target locations
    if row['Location'] in toReplace:
        # Calculate the average temperature based on the other locations
        average_temperature = row[toAverage].mean()
        
        # Update the temperature column with the calculated mean
        allData.at[index, 'Temperature'] = average_temperature`
`
# Save the updated dataset to a new CSV file
allData.to_csv('updated_allData.csv', index=False)``
```

Comment: Does it work when you use only the first 1000 rows or so?
You have a "(" in your toAverage definition, maybe a typo?